# mapply on magick-image vector

Tags: r, imagemagick, apply, mapply

I try to Rotate images with `magick::image_rotate()` for different rotation angles with `mapply` and `image_rotate` doesn't get the right input

```
easterEggs <- c(
  'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/04/20/28/easter-2038263_960_720.png',
  'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/15/11/41/easter-1908690_960_720.png',
  'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/03/28/09/56/easter-egg-2181493_960_720.png',
  'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/01/29/13/49/egg-3962420_960_720.png',
  'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/02/25/09/44/easter-3180067_960_720.png'
)

egg <- image_read(easterEggs)
eggRotation <- runif(length(egg), -90, 90)

egg <- mapply(image_rotate, egg, eggRotation)
```

This results in the Error

```
Error: The 'image' argument is not a magick image object.
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to put the eggs into a basket (i.e. a `"list"` object)

```
library(magick)
egg <- sapply(easterEggs, image_read)
eggRotation <- sapply(egg, function(x) runif(length(x), -90, 90))
```

and your `mapply` will work fine.

```
mapply(image_rotate, egg, eggRotation)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `for` loop to rotate the images

```
library(magick)

egg_new <- egg
for (i in seq_along(egg)) {
  egg_new[i] <- image_rotate(egg[i], eggRotation[i])
}
egg_new
```